# firebase cloud storage deployment under a folder

Tags: firebase-storage

Is it possible to deploy firebase cloud storage at `www.abc.com/customFolderA/customFolderB`.

Also, `www.abc.com/customFolderC` is an existing deployment which i don't want to touch.

[www.abc.com/customFolderA/customFolderB](http://www.abc.com/customFolderA/customFolderB) is Vue.js 3 withwebpack and [www.abc.com/customFolderC](http://www.abc.com/customFolderC) is legacy AngularJs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here, especially not what API you're trying to use. Can you show what you've already tried to add those files?

Comment: www.abc.com/customFolderA/customFolderB is legacy AngularJs and www.abc.com/customFolderC is Vue.js 3 withwebpack

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what doesn't work about the files in Cloud Storage. Are you asking how to set the source folder for [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)?